# int() used to slice string in half by pointing it with len() PyCharm Education excercise

Tags: python, string, int, pycharm

i would like to know why int() is used to slice a string in half /2
My current understanding is the following:

[image]

```
phrase = """
It is a really long string
triple-quoted strings are used
to define multi-line strings
"""
first_half = phrase[:int(len(phrase)/2)]
print(first_half)

#the logic behind this is the following
#phrase[:] -> int(/2) -> len(phrase)
#but because int goes before len BUT ends after len
#int(len(phrase)/2)
#__________________________________________________
#breaking down of *first_half* var
#phrase[:int(len(phrase)/2)]
#phrase[:] for a modifier of *phrase* var
#int(/2) to slice *phrase* in half
#__________________________________________________
#and len(phrase) to tell int to slice the length of
#phrase in half with /2 all of this in a variable
#and contained in a single line of code
#__________________________________________________
# BUT, WHY USE int() ?!?!?!?!? Could it be done
# in a different way?
```

Answer (score 2):

Because if you omit `int`, the division (in Python 3) will result in a floating point number when the length is an odd number and slice will raise an error:

```
>>> s = "My String"
>>> s[:len(s)/2]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

As an alternative, you could use integer division using `//` operator:

```
>>> s[:len(s)//2]
'My S'
```